# How to do a grep on expression "\e"

Tags: shell, solaris-10

I'm on SOLARIS10. The grep of this operating system doesn't accept the "-e " option. I would like to do a `grep` on the line beginning by `\e` in my log file.

I did

```
grep  "\\e" file.log
```

Doesn't work I 've got all the line of the files, and

```
grep  "/\e" file.log
```

stops on the first line that the tool met.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below grep,

`grep '^\\e' filename`

Or

Try the below sed,

```
sed -n '/^\\e/p' filename
```

Comment: @dubis the first one should, too. the **single** quotes are important.